OpenSeaMap in Qgis
I am trying to have OpenSeaMap as a map in Qgis 3.36.1. I have found some older replies to how - but no one of them works.
Have any of you any experience with OpenSeaMap in Qgis?
I can get openstreetmap to work as a XYZ Tiles without any issues.

You appear to have created two accounts. Please merge them: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts
